# Use provisioning package to upgrade Home -> Enterprise

Tags: windows-10

I would like to use a provisioning package to upgrade from Windows 10 Home to Enterprise. However, I read that [this is not directly supported](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/beanexpert/2015/08/17/how-to-upgrade-windows-10-edition-using-provisioning-package/) ("Note that you can’t upgrade from Windows 10 Home to Enterprise"). See also this [matrix of possible upgrades](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/deployment/upgrade/windows-10-edition-upgrades).

Anyway, it should be possible to update from Home to Pro, and then via command line from Pro to Enterprise. But this also doesn't work.

When I do it manually, I deactivate the internet connection, and use the generic unactivatable Windows 10 Pro key to start the update to Pro (VK7JG-NPHTM-C97JM-9MPGT-3V66T). Then I reconnect, and enter the Windows 10 Enterprise key which activates.

However, I could not even update from Home to Pro using ppkg. I tried using the generic Pro key in `UpgradeEditionWithProductKey`, but I get the following error when applying the ppkg:

> ProvXML category 'Reboot/UpgradeWindowsEdition' failed with '0xC004F016' at CSP node 'WindowsLicensing/UpgradeEditionWithProductKey'. Provisioning failed

I wonder what the problem is:

- Does the generic key not work for upgrading the windows edition?
- Or is it Windows 10 Home that does not allow the upgrade?
- Can I run a script in the ppkg *before* all the other provisioning actions? Then I could perform the upgrade manually.
- Is there another option to achive what I want, or do I have to perform the upgrade Home->Pro manually, and apply the ppkg afterwards at runtime?

Comment: "Does the generic key not work for upgrading the windows edition?" - It does not.  '0xC004F016` is an activation error.

Comment: The generic key you are using can only be used to reactivate Windows 10 Professional if you had a digital entitlement to it.  Additionally, it is the same generic key that anyone who accepted the upgrade offer to Windows 10 Professional received, and since you don't have an entitlement to Windows 10 Professional you cannot use that generic key (as evident by the activation error you received).

Comment: I see nothing that indicates [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2015/11/23/how-to-convert-windows-10-pro-to-windows-10-enterprise-using-icd/) would be limited to just Windows 10 Professional.  [This](https://www.howtogeek.com/250503/how-to-upgrade-to-windows-10-enterprise-without-reinstalling-windows/) also has nothing that specifically indicates Windows 10 Home cannot be upgraded to Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: I added some links. MS says explicity that there is no mechanism for upgrading from Home via ppkg. Regarding the activation error, I do not want to activate Windows 10 Pro. I only use that key to upgrade to Pro, so that I can then upgrade to Enterprise, without reinstalling. I can activate Enterprise with a proper key. This works fine if I do it manually.

Comment: The chart does not specifically indicate that Home -> Enterprise is not possible, it actually indicates that Home -> Education is possible, so I would go ahead and try going from Home directly to Enterprise.  Otherwise you will have to manually upgrade to Professional then upgrade the generic unactivated installation of Windows 10 per the links I provided.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. It is a bit hacky but works fine.

1. In Windows ICD, enter an invalid key for Windows 10 *Education* (`NW6C2-...`). This will cause the OS to upgrade to Education (unactivated).
2. Create a batch file with the following content (insert your Enterprise key). This sets the correct product key, and changes the edition to Enterprise.

   `slmgr //B /ipk ABCDE-12345-0000-0000-0000`
3. Add a new "application" to the ppkg, using the batch file as an installer, and `cmd /c "upgrade_edition.bat"` as a command line.

Answer (score -1):

with internet connection off or in offline mode
Open command with Admin privileges
type" slmgr /ato
Then ok to activate
Enter the Enterprise key and Voila!!!